# Keep sub-sequences of a binary list if they surpass a given length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a function that takes as input a list (or numpy array) A and a number L. A is full of 0 and 1 and the goal is to keep the sub-sequences of 1 if they surpass L in length. I wrote a function to do it fix(A,L) but it takes to long to run so I wanted to know if their is a faster way of doing this.

```
def fix(A,L):
    i=0
    while True:
        if i==len(A):
            return(A)
        if A[i]==1:
            s=0
            for j in range(i,len(A)):
                if A[j]==1:
                    s+=1
                    continue
                else:
                    if s>=L:
                        break
                    else:
                        A[i:j]=[0]*len(A[i:j])
                        break
            if A[j]==1 and s<L:
                A[i:j+1]=[0]*len(A[i:j+1])
            i=j+1
        else:
            i+=1
            continue
```

if I call `fix([1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1], 3)` it returns `[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]` which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with 2D numpy arrays, what you want to achieve can be done using binary erosion and dilation. We can use [`scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion) and  [`binary_dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation)

We're doing it here only on a single dimension:

```
np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 20))

from scipy.ndimage import binary_dilation, binary_erosion

L = 3
mask = np.ones((1, L))
binary_dilation(binary_erosion(A, mask), mask).astype(int)
```

example input:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Visual input/output:

[image: input] ➔ [image: output]

Comment: Thanks and just in case any one is wondering about the speed of this method on average it takes 0.02 seconds per image.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So 100x speedup compared to your initial approach and 40x faster than the itertools solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
def fix(A, L):
    from itertools import groupby, chain
    return list(chain.from_iterable(l if ((len(l:=list(g)) >= L and k) or not k) else [0]*len(l)
                                     for k, g in groupby(A)))
    
fix([1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1], 3)
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

###### How it works

`groupby(A)` will group per consecutive 0s or 1s. For each group we get the length and check if this is a group of 1s or 0s. If group of 0s or group of 1s of length ≥ L, we keep it, else we replace with a group of 0s of the same length. Finally, we `chain` everything to form a continuous list.

Comment: Thanks so much, the example I gave is just to demonstrate the desired outcome of the function but in reality I will be running it on huge amount of data and in that regard the speed of execution is the real problem:
my function averages  2.17 seconds while yours averages 0.85 seconds which is a good improvement so I'll accept your answer for now but if someone comes up with a better solution I'll just change the accepted solution.

Comment: @amrha if you have huge data, you should switch to a different type of container. I'd suggest maybe numpy arrays.

Comment: Well actually I am using np array, the input is A for a reason :) , any idea how to do this faster for an array?

Comment: how many elements in your real data?

Comment: I am using it on a video image by image row by row. the images are of shape (1536,2048) so I am calling the function 1536 times with lists of 2048 size for each image.

Comment: @amrha then check [this vectorial alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70679960/16343464), and let me know the timings on your dataset ;)